# Scala - avoid use mutable variables

Tags: scala

I have a function that perform a calc but i'm using a var to receive the value of a recursive function and i would like to avoid mutable variables.

```
def scoreNode(node:Option[Tree], score:Double = 0, depth:Int = 0):Double = {
  node.map(n => {
    var points = score
    n.children.filter(n => n.valid == Some(true)).foreach(h => {
      points = scoreNode(Some(h), 10, depth+1)
    })
    points
  }).getOrElse(score)
}
```

How can i rewrite this piece of code without a mutable variable? I've tried

Comment: You'll often find that any time you accept an argument of `Option` and immediately `map` on it, that your code gets easier to manage if you change the type signature to accept the non-optional type and `map` at the call site. That would remove some of the noise here and make it easier for you to see the behavior alone

Comment: What do you mean? I come from OO and FP seens obscure to me. Could you give an example?

Comment: Don't write `scoreNode(node: Option[Tree], ...) = node.map(...)` instead write `scoreNode(node: Tree, ...) = ...` and call it by `maybeNode.map(scoreNode).getOrElse(defaultScore)`

Comment: have you considered using pattern matching? Recursion and Pattern matching goes well with Scala way of doing stuff and avoiding mutation

Comment: @DevZer0 i don't know how to do it! lol

Answer (score 1):

What you are essentially doing is summing something over all the nodes in a tree. Try to write a more idiomatic code, like this.

```
def scoreNode(node:Option[Tree], depth:Int = 0):Double =
    (for {
        n <- node
        h <- n.children
        if h.valid == Some(true)
        res = scoreNode(Some(h), depth + 1) + scala.math.pow(0.8, depth)
    } yield res).sum
```

I do not guarantee this works completely. It is your homework to make it right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fold`:

```
def scoreNode(node:Option[Tree], score:Double = 0, depth:Int = 0):Double = 
  node
    .map(_.children.filter(n => n.valid == Some(true)).fold(score)((acc, h) => scoreNode(Some(h), acc + scala.math.pow(0.8, depth), depth + 1)))
    .getOrElse(score)
```

Comment: I coudn't check it to compile because `Tree` type is not given. Probably had some typo somewhere. Can you provide type for `Tree`?

Comment: is possible to avoid cast on acc and h? acc.asInstanceOf[Double]?

Comment: You can refine type for `fold` like this: `fold[Double](...`